# Defining a function for changing column values and creating new datasets

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, classification

I am trying to define a function where it will take a dataframe and change values in a column to create multiple new dataframes.

As an example, from df1 looking like:

```
df1:

  class    colB    colC
0   1      1b      1c
1   2      2b      2c
2   3      3b      3c
3   4      4b      4c
4   5      5b      5c
```

I am trying to create multiple binary classes to implement one-vs-all classification. So the function would create...

```
df2:
  class    colB    colC
0   1      1b      1c
1   -1      2b      2c
2   -1      3b      3c
3   -1      4b      4c
4   -1      5b      5c

df3:
  class    colB    colC
0   -1      1b      1c
1    1      2b      2c
2   -1      3b      3c
3   -1      4b      4c
4   -1      5b      5c

df4:
  class    colB    colC
0   -1      1b      1c
1   -1      2b      2c
2    1      3b      3c
3   -1      4b      4c
4   -1      5b      5c
```

and so on. All the unique values are an incremental value ranging from 1 to 120.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: I don't get it. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you actually want to replace with `1`, and `-1`, or do you want to add `1`/subtract `1`?

Comment: Sorry. I am trying to change the values on 'class' column and create new dataframes with the changed values. So from df1, I would end up with 5 new dataframes with changed column vales.

Comment: I am trying to create a binary classification from multi-class classification for one-vs-all training. So all the different values [1,2,3,4,5] under 'class' column would become either 1 or -1. This should happen for all the unique values...

Comment: So for df2, all the values under 'class' would be reassigned so that any values other than 1 would become -1. For df3 all the '2' would become '1' and all other values would become -1...and so it goes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `np.identity` (I changed your column name to `class_` so it's not using a protected keyword):

```
arr = np.identity(len(df1))
arr[arr==0] = -1

dfs = [df1.assign(class_=arr[:, i]) for i in range(len(df1))]

for d in dfs:
    print(d, end='\n\n')
```

```
   class_ colB colC
0     1.0   1b   1c
1    -1.0   2b   2c
2    -1.0   3b   3c
3    -1.0   4b   4c
4    -1.0   5b   5c

   class_ colB colC
0    -1.0   1b   1c
1     1.0   2b   2c
2    -1.0   3b   3c
3    -1.0   4b   4c
4    -1.0   5b   5c

   class_ colB colC
0    -1.0   1b   1c
1    -1.0   2b   2c
2     1.0   3b   3c
3    -1.0   4b   4c
4    -1.0   5b   5c

   class_ colB colC
0    -1.0   1b   1c
1    -1.0   2b   2c
2    -1.0   3b   3c
3     1.0   4b   4c
4    -1.0   5b   5c

   class_ colB colC
0    -1.0   1b   1c
1    -1.0   2b   2c
2    -1.0   3b   3c
3    -1.0   4b   4c
4     1.0   5b   5c
```

Comment: Thanks heaps. It works but getting syntax error with print(d, end='\n\n'). And what would be the easiest way to save them to a separate dataframes for each of the arrays Im getting?

Comment: The list `dfs` contains all of your DataFrames, so just access them like `dfs[0]`, `dfs[1]`, etc..

Comment: Just in case you see this, I've come across a problem with your answer, but it is my fault for not explaining the initial dataframe properly, sorry. Have posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51914247/changing-multiple-column-values-to-binary-values

Comment: @NZ_DJ I have answered the new question as well :)